# How to convert list of numbers to string without formatting

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

This is what I have so far:

```
toStr :: (Num a) => [a] -> String
toStr (x:xs)
    | length xs == 0 = []
    | length xs > 0 = show x : toStr xs
```

I keep getting this error:

```
* Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
  Expected type: [String]
    Actual type: String
```

I don't understand why it is receiving a Char instead of a [Char]. Thanks in advance.

For help, the thing I am trying to do is convert a binary list [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0] to a list like this "100110".

Comment: What's the rest of the error message?

Comment: `show` returns `String` not a `Char`. `:` takes an element and a list and returns a list. You're trying to use `:` as it would take 2 lists and return a list (i.e. like it is `++`)

Comment: You can discover what @SergeyRomanovsky told you by exploring with ghci. for example, in ghci try `:t show 5`

Comment: You can do this in one line: `toStr = (=<<) show`, but the type signature must be `toStr :: Show a => [a] -> String` or something more specific; you can't do this otherwise.

Comment: Do you deliberately intend to ignore the last element of the input list? If not the logic of your attempted implementation is wrong.

Comment: @AJFarmar ... more commonly spelled as `concatMap show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Understanding the Problem**

```
toStr :: (Num a) => [a] -> String
toStr (x:xs)
    | length xs == 0 = []
    | length xs > 0 = show x          :  toStr xs
                       ^              ^      ^
                    This is a String  |      |
                                      |  This is a String
                                   This is a function of type String -> [String] -> [String]
```

So you have:

- `show x` which is a `String`
- `toStr xs` which is a `String`
- The function `:` which expects a `String` and `[String]`.

That disagreement on `toStr xs` is a String but was expected, by `:` to be a list of Strings is the crux of the problem.  You wanted to concatenate your strings together into a single string (`show x ++ toStr xs`).

**Understanding the Next Problem***

Now you should have a few other issues. First, you have an `Num a => a` that you try to `show`.  The function `show` is not part of `Num` but instead part of the `Show` class so change `Num a =>` to `Show a =>`.

Finally, this code doesn't handle the empty list case very well:

```
 toStr (x:xs)
    | length xs == 0 = []
```

Noticing nothing comes after `x` this code will ignore the last value, `x`, and return the empty list.  It doesn't handle the case where there is no "last element" and all you have is the empty list.  To handle that try `toStr [] = []`.

**Putting it Together**

```
toStr :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
toStr [] = []
toStr (x:xs) = show x ++ toStr xs
```

with a result of:

```
> toStr [1,0,0,1,1]
"10011"
```

**Idiomatic Code**

The above is a fine result but manual primitive recursive functions aren't usually necessary when writing Haskell.  Most operations are a type of `map` or `fold` over the data.  In this case it is a mapping of the `show` function (notice how it is `show`ing every element) and a `fold` of the `++` function - also known as string concatenation.

```
toStr2 xs = foldr (++) "" (map show xs)
-- > toStr2 [1,0,0,1,1]
-- "10011"
```

Even this can be further simplified.  It is so common there exists a special function `concatMap`:

```
toStr3 xs = concatMap show xs
```

Which we can "eta reduce" (remove the outer most arguments of the function definition/application - think in terms of defining a function as another function and not the values it produced):

```
toStr4 = concatMap show
```

Alternatively, we could re-gain the original verb-age of fold and map.  The `concatMap` function is just a specific type of `fold` + `map` that works over lists.  There is a more general `foldMap` that works with any function that produces a monoid (and lists are one such structure, which means that so are Strings since they are lists of characters):

```
toStr5 = foldMap show
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Sergey, the ':' operator cannot be used, because the expression "show x" returns a string not a single character.

This code below seems to do what you wanted:

```
toStr :: (Num a, Show a) => [a] -> String
toStr (x:xs)
    | null xs         = show x  -- avoid using length because of cost
    | not (null xs)   = (show x) ++ (toStr xs)
toStr [] = ""


main = do
    let ls1 = [ 13, 17, 19, 23 ]
    let st1 = toStr ls1
    let st2 = concatMap show ls1 -- as per melpomene's remark
    putStrLn $ "st1 = " ++ st1
    putStrLn $ "st2 = " ++ st2
```

As a side remark, Haskell programmers generally avoid to use the *length* function when they just want to know whether a list is empty or not. Things can get really ugly if you do that, because of our potentially unlimited lazy lists.

Comment: The `null xs` branch is redundant.

Comment: @melpomene - yes technically you're right, we don't need the two branches. However, I feel that for this sort of questions, the OP is happier if the changes to his/her code are kept to a minimum, while still fixing the problem at hand. This is my personal bias and you may differ.

Comment: Your code has three branches, one of which is redundant. OP's code also only has two branches.

Comment: Yes, but OP's code has just two branches because it does not handle the case of an empty input list (at least as written above).